# How to use Middy with swagger

Tags: aws-lambda, swagger, swagger-ui, aws-serverless, middy

I’m quite new to using the Middy framework and I want to know how we could auto-generate swagger documentation.

The other workaround is to have a swagger file where I generate the swagger docs with code, then provision a lambda function that would show our swagger-UI page.

I will appreciate it if anyone can also point me to any resource.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

middy is agnostic to the routing, input and output structures.

If you're using `@middy/validator` you could take the JSON Schema files and transform them into OpenAPI, aka Swagger, json file that the swagger-UI can ingest. To keep the process simple it is recommended that v3.1 of the specification is used due to it being 100% compatible with JSON Schema version 2019-09.